# What does "lvalue required" mean in a C compiler error?

Tags: c, lvalue

```
 #include<stdio.h>   //line 1
 #include<conio.h>   //line 2
 void main()         //line 3
 {                   //line 4
   int a=6,g=7,b=3;    //line 5
   clrscr();           //line 6
   printf("%d",a>?g=a:g=b); //line 7
   getch();                //line 8
 }
```

Case 1: before saving the file

This will give an error at line no 7 'Lvalue required'. But when I compile no error will come and after running, it produced output 3.

Case 2 : after saving the file

And when we save this file then we get an error "Lvalue required'.

sorry for my mistake and Write question here

```
 #include<stdio.h>   //line 1
    #include<conio.h>   //line 2
    void main()         //line 3
    {                   //line 4
    int a=6,g=7,b=3;    //line 5
    clrscr();           //line 6
    printf("%d",a>b?g=a:g=b); //line 7**
    getch();                //line 8
    }
```

Case 1: before saving the file

This will give an error at line no 7 'Lvalue required'. But when I compile no error will come and after running, it produced output 3.

Case 2 : after saving the file

And when we save this file then we get an error "Lvalue required'.

Comment: Any reason you are writing `a>b?g=a:g=b;`? more readable to do `g= a>b?a:b`. Not sure whats happening in the printf. One of these 2 are probably your issue.

Comment: Well, it means that an lvalue is required, what else?

Comment: I know this but my question is after saving this error will generate.Before it will run.

Comment: how would u evaluate a>g=a if you manually parse it?

Comment: I know the syntax but my question is not about the syntax ,Its about the why the source file saved then error will come,and when we run without saving using turbo c complier no error will come

Comment: "I know the syntax" .. it doesn't appear so. In any case, remember that the C compiler only "sees" the file as it is saved on disk at the time of compilation so it may have been the case that a different version was compiled than expected.

Comment: @pst bad example, because `hi()` might return a pointer, which is absolutely valid Lvalue to make an assignment to.

Comment: Note that `a>b?g=a:g=b` is treated as `((a > b) ? g = a : g) = b`, and you really can't assign to the result of the ternary operator because it is an r-value, not an l-value.

Answer (score 5):

"Lvalue required" means you cannot assign a value to something that has no place in memory. Basically you need a variable to be able to assign a value.

in your particular case I would remove `a>g=a:g=b` and replace it with something more comprehensible, because in the current state nobody (including you and your compiler) has any slightest idea what that's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

this : printf("%d",a>g=a:g=b); makes no sense. I cant tell if you tying to make a conditional in it which you shouldn't ever do especially for something so simple.

You should read into how printf works becuase either your not understanding what is need which is something like this:

```
int a = 1;
printf("%d",a);
```

or you meant to use somthing else but I have never seen a syntax like your doing before here a>g=a:g=b.

Comment: I know Sir, but my question is different .Please read case 1 and case 2